# Push notification is not showing

Tags: cordova

I developed a phonegap application that uses push plugin. I created a sample server and the push message is not showing in the notification bar, but the message is getting in the application. Please help

My code is

var pushNotification;

```
        function onDeviceReady() {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                if( $("#home").length > 0)
                {
                    // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                    //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else
                {
                    navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
            }, false);

            try 
            { 
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"599322667326","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});     // required!
                } else {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
            catch(err) 
            { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
            } 
        }

        // handle APNS notifications for iOS
        function onNotificationAPN(e) {
            if (e.alert) {
                 $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                 navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
            }

            if (e.sound) {
                var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                snd.play();
            }

            if (e.badge) {
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
            }
        }

        // handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotificationGCM(e) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                }
                break;

                case 'message':
                    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                    if (e.foreground)
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                        my_media.play();
                    }
                    else
                    {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                        if (e.coldstart)
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
            }
        }

        function tokenHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
            // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        }

        function successHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

     </script>
```

Comment: Check whether icon is missing. Because without icon notification cant be displayed. Icon for your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these lines of code in your GCMIntentService.java onMessage() function:

```
String message = extras.getString("message");
String title = extras.getString("title");
Notification notif = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, message, System.currentTimeMillis() );
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestSampleApp.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif)
```

And import these packages

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
```

Comment: Is this still necessary? What would be needed for iOS?

Comment: @DavidNathan I think i posted this answer for older version. you can check the updated source.